# Probability of an event to occur

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

Let $X$, $Y$ be two random variables. Both $X$ and $Y$ have two possible states, denoted as $S_1$ and $S_2$. We suppose that $X$ is a function of another random variable $G$. Also, $Y$ is a function of another random variable $F$. Note that if $G$ is known, it means that we also know (the state of) $X$. The same holds for $Y$ and $F$. (We suppose that $G=F+H$, for some random variable $h$.)
**Example**: if $0\le |G| <a$ then $X=S_1=2$, and if $a\le |G| <\infty$ then $X=S_2=4$. Further if $0\le |F| <a$ then $Y=S_1=2$, and if $a\le |F| <\infty$ then $Y=S_2=4$.

Now, we define event $\mathcal{E}$ such that: $$\mathcal{E} \, \text{occurs if } \, \, w X \,\mathbb{P}(Y=X | G ) < \delta,$$ where $w$ and $\delta$ are some fixed postive constants, and where $\mathbb{P}(Y=X | G )$ denotes the probability that $Y$ has the same state as $X$ such that $G$ is known.
We assume that the probability that $X$ has state (i.e. take value) $S_k$ is known. The assumption holds also for $Y$. In addition, we assume that probability $\mathbb{P}(Y=X | G)$ is known.

**Question**: I need to compute the probability that event $\mathcal{E}$ occurs, represented by $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$.   I am interested in this kind of formulation: $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})= 1- \sum\limits_{k: \,w X \,\mathbb{P}(Y=X | G) \ge \delta} \mathbb{P}(X=S_k)$.
 Do you think that this formulation is correct ? if so, the formula is correct or it should be $\mathbb{P}(X= S_k | G)$ instead of $\mathbb{P}(X= S_k)$ ?

Comment: Why do you mix uppercase ($X,Y$) an lowercase ($f,g$) ? That's confusing, if all are random variables. Also the remark "We suppose that $g=f+h$, for some random variable $h$." is superfluos (we can always define $h=g-f$). Further, to speak of "states" is rather strange, they're just the values of the random variables, no? There are other issues (which is $S_k$), all looks contrived ... did you get this problem from somewhere?

Comment: And what is the meaning of $X$ as a multiplier?  Is $X$ a number?

Comment: @leonbloy The remark "$g=f+h$" is not that important in the problem. Aslo, by states I mean the value of $X$ (resp. $Y$), which can be $S_1$ or $S_2$ depending on the value of its correponding r.v $G$ (resp. $F$). $S_k$ is just used to represent $S_1$ and $S_2$, i.e. k=1,2. I will edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @lulu What do you mean by multiplier ? in my case $X$ can take value $S_1$ or $S_2$, which are two fixed postive numbers.

Comment: At no point did you say that $S_i$ was a positive number.  As @leonbloy says, this problem looks very contrived. As if it has a wider context you are not mentioning.  What is the meaning of $w,\delta$? $\mathscr E$ only depends on their ratio, no?  So why separate them?   I think the whole question needs editing, clarification.

Comment: @lulu I think the meaning of $w$ and $\delta$ is not important (we even can set them to $1$). My question is just about the formula I use (as mentioned in the question), is it correct? Thank you.

Comment: It's not possible for a reader to guess which things are important...you should write the question without a lot of extraneous detail.  As to the main question, it is not clear to me.  Even the definition of $\mathscr E$ is unclear.  In what space does that event occur?  My best guess is that we observe a value of $G$, call it $G_0$.  At that point $w,\delta$ are given and we know $X_0=X(G_0)$ and we are also given $P(Y=X_0|G_0)$.  We can then test the inequality $wX_0 P(Y=X_0|G_0)<\delta$.  Is that correct?  But if so, then $G$ is the driving variable...not $X$.

Comment: @lulu Your guess is $100$% correct. So you mean that in my formula, the  sum over $k$ ($2$ possible states, i.e. $k=1,2$) is incorrect ? if so, what is the correct formula of $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ ? Could you please provide an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I am interpreting this correctly, but here goes:

The way I read the question:  $S_1,S_2$ are two positive real numbers.  $X,Y$ are two random variables with values in $S=\{S_i\}$.  No assumption is made about the independence of $X$, $Y$.  $G$ is another random variable (let's say it's real valued though this is not specified) and we are told that $X$ is determined by $G$.   We are told all values of the conditional probabilities $P(Y=X|G)$ (that is, this conditional probability is known for all values of $G$).  We are also given two positive constants $w,\delta$.

Given all that, the experiment in question is as follows:  observe a value of $G$, call it $G_0$.  The experiment has a positive outcome if the expression $wX(G_0)P(Y=X_0|G_0)<\delta$ and a negative outcome otherwise.  We let $\mathscr E$ denote the event that this experiment has a positive outcome and we seek to compute $P(\mathscr E)$.  If, say, $G$ is specified by a density $g(t)$ then $$P(\mathscr E)=\int_{t|\;wX(t)P(Y=X(t)|t)<\delta}g(t)dt$$  If you want to express this via the complement then of course $$P(\mathscr E)=1-P(\mathscr E^c)=1- \int_{t|\;wX(t)P(Y=X(t)|t)≥\delta}g(t)dt$$

(N.B.  I am not sure that any of this is useful.)